# Move ImageView inside CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, cardview

I am trying to move an ImageView around inside a CardView. I have a CardView with some text and an ImageView, and I would like to place my circular ImageView above the text in the center.

In the picture you can see the green drawable circle in the top left of the CardView, and the TextView centered. [ImageView stuck at top left of CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr0pY.png)

Here is my current code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomePageActivity"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium">
```

... Inside the ConstraintLayout I have:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/create_invoice_cardview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_gap_normal"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_width_normal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_gap_normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_single_cardview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/capture_receipt_cardview"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/inset_background"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:text="Create Invoice"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25sp"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have tried using inset in the inset_background drawable, but it just squishes the circle into an oval and does not move it.

**How am I able to move the ImageView inside the CardView while keeping the drawable shape a circle?**

I would like this solution to resize accordingly when I modify the phone screen size. i.e I don't want a hard-coded size that is small on a Pixel XL and big on a Nexus 4.

To give a better idea of what I am looking for, [this is what I am trying to design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwBNM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `ImageView` and `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:text="Create Invoice"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically this LinearLayout will align items below each other. By setting `gravity center` to the ImageView, it will be properly centered. Since it is declared before the ImageView it will appear above it.

Comment: In this solution, the ImageView size is based on the size of the drawable (wrap content for height and width). How can I change this so that the drawable isn't a fixed value but scales with the size of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/create_invoice_cardview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_single_cardview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/capture_receipt_cardview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_gap_normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_width_normal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_gap_normal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/inset_background"
                android:centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25sp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:text="Create Invoice" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```